# what does the keyword assert means in java?

Tags: java, gwt, assert

i saw  somewhere in GWT code , it was something like this

```
assert display instanceof Widget : "display must extend Widget";
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `assert` keyword, as the name implies, makes an *assertion* about the code. It is used to specify something that holds true all the time -- or that, at least, should be true!

The `assert` keyword is followed by a boolean value (`true` or `false`), or an expression, to be evaluated at runtime, that returns a boolean.

```
assert true;
assert 1 == 1;
```

If, for any reason, the boolean expression evaluates to false, then an `AssertionError` is thrown.

```
// this will throw an AssertionError:
int x = 1;
assert x == 2;
```

When you use it, you make a clear statement about the state of your program on a given point, which can make it easier for readers to follow through your code.

There's a programming paradigm called **program by contract**, in which pieces of code make statements about the pre-conditions that must hold true for them to execute properly, and the post-conditions, that are guaranteed to hold true after their execution. You can use the `assert` keyword to implement this.

For example, if you write a method that calculates the square root of a number, it will only work for numbers that are greater than or equal to zero, and the result is guaranteed to satisfy the same conditions:

```
public double sqrt(final double x) {
    assert x >= 0 : "Cannot calculate the square root of a negative number!"
    double result = ...;
    assert result >= 0 : "Something went wrong when calculating the square root!"
    return result;
}
```

The most interesting aspect of assertions is that **you can ask the compiler to remove them from the bytecode** (by means of the `-disableassertion` argument), so that you won't get any kind of performance penalty at runtime on production. For this precise reason, **it is of fundamental importance that the expression to be evaluate does not cause side-effects**, that is, the expression should look like a pure mathematical function. Otherwise, the behavior of your program could change if the compiler removed your assertions.

Finally, if the assertions are compiled into the bytecode, they can be read by a software that will automatically generate tests that will try to break your code. It can be useful to find bugs earlier!

Comment: so if i dont ask compiler to remove em from the final bytecode , and something goes wrong and as you said boolean expression evaluates to false , it will throw Exception at runtime , right ?

Comment: Actually, it will throw an `AssertionError`, which is a subclass of Error, which is a subclass of `Throwable`. Exception is another subclass of `Throwable`, but with different semantics. You can think of `Error` as something *much worse* than an `Exception`. Exceptions are there so that you can separate your "main code" from the code that deals with problems that can occur at runtime (IOException, for example). Errors are thrown when something much worse, and usually unrecoverable, is happening, such as OutOfMemoryError, or StackoverflowError.

Comment: Your goal is to make your code such that it will **never** throw an `AssertionError`, since this would mean that your code is not being used correctly (ie, the preconditions that must be satisfied for it to run correctly aren't quite satisfied!).

Comment: so it is like a IF condition and , it will throw the throw new AssertionError ( message ) exception , if condition is satisfied  , but with the advantage of -it-can-be-removed-from-the-bytecode- .

Comment: If you want to try **program by contract** in Java, an starting point could be Google's Guava library. It contains a class called `Preconditions`, which has static methods that take expressions and strings, and work almost like the `assert` keyword. The main differences are: (1) Guava will throw unchecked exceptions rather than AssertionError; (2) the methods have more semantical names, such as Preconditions.checkNotNull(myParameter); (3) They cannot be automatically remove by the compiler.

Comment: About your last comment: yes, exactly!

Comment: so when u said "The most interesting aspect of assertions is that you can ask the compiler to remove them from the bytecode, so that you won't get any kind of performance penalty at runtime on production." , how do i ask compiler to remove asserted codes ? is it some tricks or just pass some arguments and done

Comment: You just pass an argument to the compiler: `javac -disableassertion MyClass.java`. The argument itself takes arguments, so you can selectively disable assertions on some classes, and keep them enabled on others.

Comment: You can also enable or disable the assertions at runtime (when they are not removed by the compiler), look at the `-ea` command line argument.

Answer (score 3):

The [assert keyword](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/lang/assert.html) was introduced in 1.4 (follow that link for a complete description).  It is a shorthand to throw an exception at runtime if a condition is not satisfied.

Think of it as

```
assert condition : message
```

as

```
if ( ! condition ) {
    throw new AssertionError ( message ) ;
}
```

The idea is to give developers an easy way to help users (in your case GWT API users) to detect common errors/pitfalls

When it was introduced, the `assert` statement became a reserved word and that caused a few compilation issues when old code was recompiled for I.4.  Especially for JUnit test suites where there was a much used `assert()` method.  JUnit reacted by replacing assert with `assertTrue()`

Answer (score 0):

It means that if display isn't an object of type Widget, you'll get an AssertionError with the text string that follows the assertion. Assertions are helpful for debugging.

Comment: so its just useful when debugging , nothing to do with runtime code execution , right ?

Comment: Well, it probably shouldn't be used for control flow, if that's what you mean. If your assertions prove untrue in your final product, I think that means you've gone very wrong somewhere!

Answer (score 0):

assert keyword is used to simplify the userdefined exception.what happens,to define a userdefined exception we have to create our own exception class by defining the exception causing condition first then we have to throw that in our program.
but from java 1.5 onwards we have a keyword as assert where only we have to write assert(condition)  if condtion is true it executes the other part of the program or else if it is false the it creates the object of AssertionError class and we have to handle it.
so no need to define our userdefind error.

Answer (score 0):

**The following text (emphasis mine) explains various forms of assertions clearly:**

---

> The assertion statement has two forms.
>
> *The first, simpler form is:*
>
> **assert Expression1 ;**
>
> where Expression1 is a boolean expression. When
> the system runs the assertion, it evaluates Expression1 and if it is
> false throws an AssertionError with no detail message.
>
> *The second form of the assertion statement is:*
>
> **assert Expression1 : Expression2 ; (Your example falls here)**
>
> where: Expression1 is a boolean expression. Expression2 is an expression that
> has a value. (It cannot be an invocation of a method that is declared
> void.) Use this version of the assert statement to provide a detail
> message for the AssertionError. The system passes the value of
> Expression2 to the appropriate AssertionError constructor, which uses
> the string representation of the value as the error's detail message.

*Also, refer the following oracle link for detailed information:*
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/assert.html